# Xaml Entry MVVM Databinding

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

i`m trying to Connect Entry in the Xaml to the ViewModel.
The Problem is that the Entry doesn´t fire a PropertyChanged Event.

```
  <Entry FontSize="Large"
         Placeholder="3"
         Keyboard="Numeric"
         Text="{Binding BaseValue, StringFormat='{0}', Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The Consturter initializes the Entry with a Value, which fires an PropertyChanged, but when i enter something in the Textfield the displayed Field Changes but the PropertyChanged  isn´t triggered...
I konw i could use the OnEntryTextChanged event in the View but i want to use Databindings to get "perfect"MVVM. Is there an possibility to acchieve that?

```
class PowersViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
     double baseValue = 4;
     public PowersViewModel()
            {BaseValue = baseValue;}
     public double BaseValue
            {
                private set
                {
                    SetProperty(ref baseValue, value);
                }
                get
                {
                    return baseValue;
                }
            }
}
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
                                  [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste in your view model. Also, what is an `Entry`?

Comment: Entry is the field where you can write something with a Keyboard.

Comment: Oh, OK. I didn't notice the "xamarin.forms" tag.

Comment: Does changing the private set to a protected or public one help?

Comment: Have you tried setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in you `Binding`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `PowersViewModel` you are doing:-

```
public double BaseValue
{
    private set
    {
        SetProperty(ref baseValue, value);
    }
    get
    {
        return baseValue;
    }
}
```

By doing so, any changes that you make to the `Entry` will not be stored back in your `ViewModel`.

If you change this property to:-

```
public double BaseValue
{
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref baseValue, value);
    }
    get
    {
        return baseValue;
    }
}
```

you will see that the changes are persisted back in your `ViewModel`.

Try out the example below that also displays a `Button` that you can click to check the value in your `ViewModel` and it will display an alert of the actual value.  If you change your `private set` to `set` you will then see that the message displayed, displays the current correct value as displayed in the `Entry` control.

**Example:-**

```
StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout();

Entry objEntry = new Entry()
{
    FontSize = 20,
    Placeholder = "3",
    Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric
};
//
objEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "BaseValue", BindingMode.TwoWay);
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objEntry);


PowersViewModel objViewModel = new PowersViewModel();

this.BindingContext = objViewModel;


Button objButton  = new Button();
objButton.Text = "Check value";
objButton.Clicked+=((o2,e2)=>
{
    DisplayAlert("",string.Format("BaseValue={0}", objViewModel.BaseValue), "OK");
});
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objButton);
```

**Supporting Class**:-

```
class PowersViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    double baseValue = 4;
    public PowersViewModel()
    { BaseValue = baseValue; }
    public double BaseValue
    {
        //private set - incorrect!
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref baseValue, value);
        }
        get
        {
            return baseValue;
        }
    }
}
```